# what does the function argument in the mocha method "it" take as it's return value

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

this question concerns `it()` function in the javascript library mocha.

it is about the return value of the it() argument function that mocha uses in it's test suites.

my assumption is that all the methods of chai either return a true or a false.

basically I am wondering what assertions libraries such as [chai](http://chaijs.com/) return.

I am wondering if something like this will work.

```
describe("example test suite", function(){
    it("tests a thing", function(){
         var myVar = "foo";
         if(myVar!==undefined){return true}
         else{return false}
    });
});
```

is this something that would work?
if not, what is the return value from assertion libraries like chai?

Comment: Assertion methods don't return anything.

Comment: then how do the assertion methods pass that info to a testing framework?

Comment: By throwing an exception or logging to global state.

Comment: alright that makes sense. thank you very much!